# The Web Script /share/page/api/javascript/debugger has responded with a status of 500

Tags: java, linux, alfresco, javascript-debugger

I installed Alfresco 4.2c on CentOS.

To enable JavaScript debugging, I go to http://localhost:8080/share/page/api/javascript/debugger and click on the `Enable` button:

[image]

Unfortunately, clicking this button just shows the error below:

[image]

```
Surf Web Script Status 500 - Internal Error

The Web Script /share/page/api/javascript/debugger has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.

500 Description:    An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Message:    01210001 Wrapped Exception (with status template): null

Exception:  org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 01210001 Wrapped Exception (with status template): null

    org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1067)

Server: Spring WebScripts - v1.2.0 (Release 1207) schema 1,000
Time:   Feb 21, 2018 12:06:58 PM

Diagnostics:    Inspect Web Script (org/springframework/extensions/webscripts/jsdebugger.post)
```

The catalina.out log contains:

```
 2018-02-21 12:00:08,675  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-apr-8080-exec-5] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 01210000 Wrapped Exception (with status template): null
 org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 01210000 Wrapped Exception (with status template): null
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.PresentationContainer.executeScript(PresentationContainer.java:70)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.LocalWebScriptRuntimeContainer.executeScript(LocalWebScriptRuntimeContainer.java:240)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:377)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.mvc.WebScriptView.renderMergedOutputModel(WebScriptView.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.MTAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(MTAuthenticationFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SSOAuthenticationFilter.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at jp.co.ichijo.alfresco.share.web.site.servlet.IchijoFilter.doFilter(IchijoFilter.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at jp.co.ichijo.alfresco.share.web.site.servlet.AutoAddRequestHeaderFilter.doFilter(AutoAddRequestHeaderFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at jp.co.ichijo.alfresco.share.web.site.servlet.AddRequestHeaderFilter.doFilter(AddRequestHeaderFilter.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1813)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:224)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.SwingGui.<init>(SwingGui.java:152)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptDebugger$AlfrescoGui.<init>(ScriptDebugger.java:165)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptDebugger.activate(ScriptDebugger.java:86)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptDebugger.show(ScriptDebugger.java:104)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.bean.JavascriptDebuggerPost.executeImpl(JavascriptDebuggerPost.java:61)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.executeImpl(DeclarativeWebScript.java:235)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:64)
    ... 43 more
2018-02-21 12:06:58,230  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-apr-8080-exec-5] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 01210001 Wrapped Exception (with status template): null
 org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 01210001 Wrapped Exception (with status template): null
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.PresentationContainer.executeScript(PresentationContainer.java:70)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.LocalWebScriptRuntimeContainer.executeScript(LocalWebScriptRuntimeContainer.java:240)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:377)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.mvc.WebScriptView.renderMergedOutputModel(WebScriptView.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.MTAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(MTAuthenticationFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SSOAuthenticationFilter.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at jp.co.ichijo.alfresco.share.web.site.servlet.IchijoFilter.doFilter(IchijoFilter.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at jp.co.ichijo.alfresco.share.web.site.servlet.AutoAddRequestHeaderFilter.doFilter(AutoAddRequestHeaderFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at jp.co.ichijo.alfresco.share.web.site.servlet.AddRequestHeaderFilter.doFilter(AddRequestHeaderFilter.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1771)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:224)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.SwingGui.<init>(SwingGui.java:152)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptDebugger$AlfrescoGui.<init>(ScriptDebugger.java:165)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptDebugger.activate(ScriptDebugger.java:86)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptDebugger.show(ScriptDebugger.java:104)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.bean.JavascriptDebuggerPost.executeImpl(JavascriptDebuggerPost.java:61)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.executeImpl(DeclarativeWebScript.java:235)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:64)
    ... 43 more
```

My Java version:

```
# yum list installed | grep openjdk
java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64             1:1.6.0.41-1.13.13.1.el6_8       @base    
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64             1:1.7.0.161-2.6.12.0.el6_9       @updates 
java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64             1:1.8.0.161-3.b14.el6_9          @updates 
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64    1:1.8.0.161-3.b14.el6_9          @updates
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install the latest Oracle Java SE (With CentOS' OpenJDK package I have only been able to install the headless version, whereas we need the full version with AWT/Swing)
2. In `tomcat/bin/setenv.sh` set `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` to its path, for instance `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161`
3. In `tomcat/scripts/ctl.sh` remove all occurrences of `-Djava.awt.headless=true` you see.

If you are running the graphical user interface (you need one for the debugger) under another user than the user running Alfresco, you will get an error `java.awt.HeadlessException - No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.`. I fixed it by adding lines `DISPLAY=":0.0"` and `export DISPLAY` in `tomcat/bin/setenv.sh` but then I got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment` so I just gave up and ran the desktop environment as the alfresco user, which solved the error:

[image]